# Python - Searching specific hex bytes in a series of Hex bytes using Python

Tags: python, string, search, hex

Input Bytes: 35 04 65 FF D0 00 10 24 D0 01 10 24 E0 20 10 2C 84 D0 05 10 24 D0 07 10 24
I have a series of bytes as above. coming out of a diagnostics tool. I want to search for "E0 20" and need to retrieve the next 3 bytes from that.

eg., The 3 Bytes follows E0 20 is .....  10 2C 84..

How to do this, what are the inbuilt support available fore this in Python?

regards,.
Joseph

I tried and found solution for similar problems. But I as a begineer, I wanted to understand the efficient method of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1) Regular expressions

If we generalize this to the problem of extracting string matches, then regular expressions (RegEx) are useful. The general way you solve a string matching problem with RegEx is like this:

- Think of what you want to extract, and what the inputs should look like
- Create a regex pattern which matches what you're looking for. I suggest adding parentheses around the subpattern you'd like to extract so you can use group pattern extraction.
- Optionally, compile the regex for better performance.

Here's a working example which extract the 3 letter following a subpattern.

```py
import re

# Matches on the literal "hello my name is " and then
# makes a group extraction to collect the next 3 letters
pattern  = re.compile("hello my name is ([a-zA-Z]{3})")

# First example shouldn't have a match.
# The following examples should have their 3 first letters extracted.
examples = [
    "",
    "hello my name is Bob",
    "hello my name is Alice"
]

for example in examples:
  matches = pattern.findall(example)
  
  # A match is not guaranteed.
  # findall may return multiple matches as well.
  # Consider changing `findall` to a different regex method
  # as needed.
  if matches:
    print(matches)

# Outputs:
# ['Bob']
# ['Ali']
```

Approach 2) Do a single loop over the input bytes

In your case, since you're looking for an exact string match, RegEx might be overkill. You can probably get away with doing a single loop over the input string to extract a match, if any. I won't provide an example for this, but here's a sketch:

```
for i, byte_chunk in enumerate(input_bytes):
   if byte_chunk == TARGET_BYTE_CHUNK:
     do_something_with_byte_chunks(i + 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The bytes object has a [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.find) method that you could use to locate the sequence you are interested in.

For example:

```py
input_data = bytes.fromhex('35 04 65 FF D0 00 10 24 D0 01 10 24 E0 20 10 2C 84 D0 05 10 24 D0 07 10 24')
search_data = bytes.fromhex('E0 20')
data_len = 3

data_start = input_data.find(search_data) + len(search_data)
data_out = input_data[data_start: data_start + data_len]
print(f"{data_out.hex()}")
# '102c84'
```